# Find RAM/CPU usage by service

Tags: services

I have a `systemctl` service running. I want to find its RAM/CPU usage. How can I do that in terminal (without any UI, because it's on remote server)? And without 3rd party tools, if possible. `free` doesn't tell me a lot, only Mem and Swap for overall system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use top or htop which both are terminal system monitor, to get info of a single PID call them with:

```
top -p $PID
htop -p $PID
```

where $PID is the process you want to monitor

Comment: While your answer is correct, could you please also explain how to obtain the process ID of a systemd service?

Comment: due the systemctl status $servicename pid should listened in there